# Django models: Unique values for foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

I am building an Instagram like app and trying to make a like model. Each user can like a post however, it should not be possible to like the same post twice.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is my model however, I am able to create 2 identical objects. For example user 1 can have 2 like objects like to post 1.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can mark the *combination* of the `user` and `post` field as unique with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'post'], name='like_once')
        ]
```

Prior to [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of the [**`unique_together`** option [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'post']]
```

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).